# Supercontinoum lasers

Tags: laser, non-linear-systems, non-linear-optics

In my work I've encountered the phrase "supercontinuoum (CW) laser" quite a bit. After reading the wikipedia page, I'm interested in a more theoretical introductory. I'm mostly interested in

**Propogation Dynamics and Model**. the NLS model is monochromatic, characterized by some principal wave number $k_0$, I wonder what are the different equations that are used to study supercontinuoum, and what are the main results about its propogation.

Thanks!

Comment: [This article](https://www.rp-photonics.com/supercontinuum_generation.html) describes the physics, and provides many references.  All of my exposure is to super-continua generated by ultrafast pulses.  The processes are all very non-linear.

Comment: It's true that analytic solutions generally don't exist for the NLS in the context of supercontinuum calculations, but this doesn't mean that the NLS can't still be used. In practically all supercontinuum simulations, numerical solutions to the NLS (or the generalized NLS if delayed nonlinear material response is included) are found instead. See the split-step Fourier and the Runge-Kutta fourth-order interaction picture methods for some examples of numerical integration techniques, then the local error and the conservation quantity error methods for balancing accuracy with  computation time.